# Reference to another project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I create a reference to another project (a library) thats part of the same solution in Visual Studio, is that project then compiled into my assembly, or does it link to the assembly created by the other project? I'm wondering if I need to distribute both assemblies, or if I can distribute just one.

If the latter (have to distribute both), how can I force it to compile into one assembly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is that project then compiled into my assembly, or does it link to the assembly created by the other project?

The other project is in its own assembly; it's not compiled into yours.

> I'm wondering if I need to distribute both assemblies, or if I can distribute just one.

You have to distribute both.

> how can I force it to compile into one assembly?

There's no built-in way to do this with Visual Studio, other than moving the source code from the other project into the main one. You could take a look at [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 2):

By default the library project will produce a separate assembly/dll. According to this post

[Linking statically in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116/linking-statically-in-c)

you can use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx) though to merge these separate dlls into a combined one though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pre-build action on project's property page to copy source files from other project(s) into main.
This way you'll only modify source in one place and always have a separate dll as an option. When you'll decide to use dll remove copied source files and pre-build action and add reference to library project(s)

Answer (score 1):

If you reference another project then the compiler will generate a dll file for each project required to execute the overall solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Solution file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951%28VS.80%29.aspx) is used to just work easily, and manage projects it doesn't make any change to manner of default projects, may be you want install shield? have different Dlls is not bad thing, you can grow your Main project better.