# Winforms logging framework

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I'm writing a WinForms application. I need to log information into a file. Usually I use [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) for logging, but I cannot add the reference, due to a restriction. I **cannot add external** references to my project, because I must deploy a single executable.

Is there any built-in **logging framework** in .NET so I will be able to log into a file without adding an external dll?

P.S: Of course I don't wanna open a stream and write manually.

Comment: If .NET framework shipped a full-blown logging framework there would be no need for log4net in the first place...

Comment: @Alex not all .NET functionality is brilliant, there are various external libraries that replace parts of the framework because they're doing a better job at it.

Comment: @Daniel where does this requirement come from? Is [merging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116/linking-statically-in-c-sharp) the assemblies an option?

Comment: .NET does ship with a full blown logging framework, just one with a sensible amount of severity levels

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the [System.Diagnostics.TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx) class. You will need to define the TRACE constant for it to work, but you can use a number of built in tracelisteners, through configuration of your app.config:

- [ConsoleTraceListener Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.consoletracelistener)
- [EventLogTraceListener Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogtracelistener)
- [XmlWriterTraceListener Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.xmlwritertracelistener)
- [TextWriterTraceListener Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener)

The app.config looks something like this if you want to write to a file, there are a lot of filters you can also add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
          <listeners>
            <add name="yourName" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\mylogfile.txt" />
          </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

And usage:

```
Trace.TraceError("There's been an error captain: {0}", e);
Trace.TraceWarning("The system broke but don't worry.");
Trace.TraceInformation("Starting up the engines.");
```

Personally I wouldn't write to a text file if you can avoid it, the Event Log is a better location as you can sort, filter, the logs are auto-purged and you don't get file lock up issues.

Comment: What is "yourName" in the listener?

Comment: @DanielPeñalba the name doesn't matter too much unless you reference it in code via `Trace.Listeners["yourName"]`

Comment: @ChrisS Nothing is being written in my log file. Any reasons why?

Comment: @reggie Did you define #TRACE in your project properties?

Answer (score 8):

Well, if you're comfortable with log4net so be it. Use the logging tool of your choice, and in post-build use [ILMerge](https://github.com/Microsoft/ILMerge) to merge all dependencies into a single executable.

This is exactly the scenario that it is intended for.

There's also a [GUI](https://github.com/jpdillingham/ILMergeGUI) for it, if you don't want to use it in command line mode.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the system trace calls, but it's a poor substitute for a proper logging framework like log4net.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx

An alternative, and maybe more flexible long term, approach would be to use ILMerge to combine all your external DLLs into a single executable after you've compiled everything.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630

Or package everything as an MSI or clickonce package of course depending on your definition of "single executable".

Answer (score 0):

The following page shows an example of logging manually to an XML file. Looks reasonably simple.

[c# Best Method to create a log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242061/c-sharp-best-method-to-create-a-log-file)

Hope it helps.