# Activating logging for a Winform Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, logging, trace

I came across this: [Winforms logging framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409264/winforms-logging-framework)

But, I cannot get it working.

In the app.config, I have the following:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="yourName" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\mylogfile.txt" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics
```

In my code, I have the following to write to the log file:

```
Trace.Write("test");
Trace.TraceError("There's been an error captain: {0}", e);
Trace.TraceWarning("The system broke but don't worry.");
Trace.TraceInformation("Starting up the engines.");
```

The file is created. But nothing is written to it. Trace is turned on in visual studio.

Not sure what is missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've turned off autoflush. Try setting autoflush to true or calling `Trace.Flush` at the end of your code sample.