# Referencing a project in another project creates unwanted dependencies

Tags: c#, reference, projects-and-solutions

I have a project `ProjectA` in which I am keeping utility classes. I want to use this project in multiple solutions so I do not have to copy files, link files and update files every time I make changes in classes of `Project`.

But there seems to be a problem: if I am referencing `ProjectA` in `ProjectB`, the compiled application of `ProjectB` can not run unless there's a compiled application from `ProjectA` next to it. So if the output of `ProjectB` is ProjectB.exe, ProjectB.exe gives an error upon execution if ProjectA.exe is not next to it. Why is that? I just want to use namespaces from `ProjectA` in `ProjectB`, I do not need `ProjectA` to depend on a compiled version of `ProjectB`.

Can anyone tell me how to reference `ProjectA` in `ProjectB` without needing the output of `ProjectA` to run the output of `ProjectB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a shared dll.

You have created utility classes in project A out because they are shared all across project A (Application A?), now you have introduced project B (Application B) and as you state it needs to get hold of the code from projectA.dll/exe.

So create a new project in your solution (Ab.Shared.dll maybe:-)) and move your utiilty classes into it. You can now reference that dll from both project A and project B.

**Update**: Just read about your comment about sucking code out.

The shared dll is the most common way of sharing the code about, but there are other ways. Theoretically you can simply "include" the same *.cs files in both projects and share them that way (use the drop down on the Add existing item dialog and select Add as link) . However in practice it becomes more awkward maintaining this scenario so most people use a shared dll.

Comment: `ProjectA` is an utility project in its entirety, so I'm using it only to keep track of shared code and to update that shared code a lot easier. Only `ProjectB` actually outputs a dll/exe. What I basically want is for `ProjectB` to suck code from `ProjectA` when it is getting compiled, without actually depending on a compiled dll/exe of `ProjectA`.

Comment: In which case you are probably confusing a project with a namespace (which is very common). You don't need to use a project, instead just add a folder to ProjectB, and drag your files out of project A

Comment: Yup, you're right. I just need to use a folder, and not a project. The funny thing is that I was using a folder in the beginning and then for some reason in the past I thought that using a project as a container is a better idea. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the nDepend documentation. As well as the application itself (which I heartily recommend for larger solutions) Patrick has some really good documentation to get you into the right mindset. Try http://ndepend.com/Res/NDependWhiteBook_Assembly.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces are not restricted to one assembly - you can use the same namespace across several assemblies if you wish, and one assembly can contain as many namespaces as you like.

If you are referencing a class/type from another assembly, then that assembly must be present (or locatable) when you run the original assembly. If all you are doing is coding then a simple [project reference in your solution](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/29/add-reference-dialog-improvements-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) will do the trick. If you don't have the source code to `Project A` then you will need it in its compiled form - without it the CLR cannot inspect it and know what it contains.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Apparently I was wrong thinking that a project would be a better container rather than a mere folder, but as AlSki suggested, adding a folder containing the .cs shared files is enough.

Answer (score 0):

In that case add the `ProjectA` compiled dll in your bin folder and add the reference to that dll from your other project. Do not add reference to your `ProjectA` project.

When you add reference to the project using Visual studio, Add Reference -> Projects, then it requires the project to be compiled and it copies the dll/exe to the other project bin folder.

Comment: The reason I'm referencing the `ProjectA` is because `ProjectB` can see the changes in `ProjectA` immediately, and if I update namespaces in `ProjectA`, refactoring updates them in `ProjectB` as well, and I believe that is not possible if I add the compiled dll or `ProjectA`. Furthermore, then I would depend on that dll. Isn't there a way for `ProjectB` to suck the code from `ProjectA` when compiling `ProjectB`?

Comment: For your first part of question, you will have to add reference to the project and it should be able to compile itself as well. For 2nd part of question, I am not really sure, multiple dlls could be merged into a single project, but I don't think you can do that from visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Open your **csproj** file in text editor and insert xml:

```
<Reference Include="AssemblyName.dll">
  <HintPath>$(EnvironmentVariable)\bin\AssemblyName.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have code in ProjectA.exe that you want to use in ProjectB.exe, but at run time, you'd like to run ProjectB.exe without requiring the user to have a copy of ProjectA.exe.

This is not possible.  When you use a type from another assembly, that assembly is loaded at run time.  The type is not copied from ProjectA to ProjectB.

It sounds to me like you should extract the common utility classes into ProjectUtility.dll, and then reference that from both your ProjectA.exe and ProjectB.exe applications.

EDIT: ILMERGE might be the way to go.  See [Linking statically in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39116/385844) for more information.

Comment: `ProjectA` is just a project, that's all. I do not intend to have it output to a dll or exe, I just want to keep code organized in it and access it from other projects (which I intend to compile to exes or dlls). The way I was doing it before was by linking .cs files from `ProjectA` to `ProjectB`, but that was a pain to maintain because it needed updating every time I changed namespaces or source .cs file location.

Comment: @IneedHelp the project *does* create a dll or exe, as you've discovered.  The only other way I would know to do what you want is to use your earlier approach of linking the files.  The usual approach to separating out common code is to keep it in a library (which is what the second "l" in "dll" stands for, after all).

Comment: @IneedHelp apparently you can use ILMERGE to merge two assemblies after compilation.  See this SO answer (though it is old and might be obsolete): http://stackoverflow.com/a/39147/385844

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. It seems I only needed to use a folder, as AlSki suggested. So I'm creating a symbolic link to the shared folder in every project.